# sqlite3 python2.7 and Ubuntu 10.04 (or just python2.6)

Tags: python, ubuntu, sqlite

Question:  How can I get my non-system Python2.7 to find the sqlite3 libraries?

Details:

I run Ubuntu 10.04 LTS which uses Python2.6.

I have projects that require Python2.7.  I use the `--python=Python2.7` flags for virtualenv to have my project use that.

I have the following sqlite3 stuff installed

> libsqlite3-0                    - SQLite 3 shared library
>   libsqlite3-dev                  - SQLite 3 development files
>   sqlite3                         - A command line interface for SQLite 3

I can import and use sqlite3 fine with Python2.6.  But, not so lucky with Python2.7.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Sep 18 2011, 19:55:45) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

This is how I got Python2.7 on the machine

```
tar xzf Python-2.7.tgz
cd Python-2.7
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

A recompile of python2.7 did the trick.

Comment: I find this too, however I feel there should be an easier way!